# How to set the enable property to a highcharts line in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

If you want to understand my requirement , first you have to see this demo [highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels/grid)
. Now click on Tokyo from that demo chart, that tokyo line will be dissappear. Now I want to able to set that property in page load, **I mean whenever the page is loaded, the tokyo link should be clicked and only one line should display, when I click on Tokyo then the tokyo line should display**. You can find the source code from that demo itself Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is a way to make only the clicked legend series show. If that is the case you can do it with the [`plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick). To have only one series show up initially on the chart (but still show in the legend) you need to set that series' [`visible`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible) property to `true` and the others to `false`. If you want to have all series show on initial load that step can be ignored.

To get the toggle working you need to get the index of the legend item you clicked. You then loop through all the series in your chart to find the one that matches that clicked index. When it matches you set [`series\[i\].show()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show) for the ones that don't you set [`series.hide()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide).

Here is the basic toggling code:

```
series: {
    events: {
        legendItemClick: function (event) {
            var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var serie = this.chart.series;
            console.log(seriesIndex);
            for (i = 0; i < serie.length; i++) {                  
                if (serie[i].index == seriesIndex) {
                    serie[i].show();
                    console.log(serie[i].index);
                } else {
                    serie[i].hide();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/7HGM9/).

Answer (score 1):

When creating chart, just set `series.visible = false` for series which should be hidden by default.

See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible).

Comment: it should not be hidden, it should be displayed as enabled false.

Comment: Create simple mockup, it's not clear what you want to achieve, sorry.